# Cannot read property of undefined in React Native style

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to access my `styles` property as usual, however, I'm getting an error: `Cannot read property 'swipeButtonCommon' of undefined`.

Well, my `styles` object is defined as has `swipeButtonCommon` anyway:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ...
    swipeButtonCommon:{
        backgroundColor: Color.listActionBackground
    },
   ...
   //swipeButtonLeft and swipeButtonRight are also defined
})

function SwipeButton(title:string, side: 'left' | 'center' | 'right'){
    let styleClass: string | null = null;

    if(side == 'left'){
        styleClass = 'swipeButtonLeft';
    }else if(side == 'right'){
        styleClass = 'swipeButtonRight'
    }
    return (
        <View style={[styles.swipeButtonCommon, styles[styleClass!]]}><Text>{title}</Text></View>
    )
}
```

I'm getting the error in `<View style={...}` line, and even though I have a breakpoint set, it's not hitting for some reason. I've cleared the Metro Bundler cache and Haste module map, and I've restarted pretty much everything, though no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u define styles of `swipeButtonLeft` and `swipeButtonRight ` ???

Comment: did you try printing `styles` inside `SwipeButton` func and see what gets printed? Also can you post the full code in the file?

Comment: @HardikVirani yes they are defined.

Comment: @yaswanth it prints `undefined`

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu can you post the full code in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. I was using `function ComponentName()` syntax which I'm normally not used to. I've switched to regular `class ComponentName extends Component` syntax and the problem went away.